# Apache Camel - Redis Module - FCALL

Tags: redis, apache-camel

I am trying to call a custom method inside of Redis (FCALL method 1 test:1 key value key value) via camel and am running into a issue and im not sure if its a "Camel doesn't support FCALL" or i'm just doing it wrong. the camel redis does not show this being a valid command, so im assuming it doesn't handle it but wanted to confirm this is true.

Camel Router:

```
from("file://data/test_dir_1")
  .setHeader(RedisConstants.COMMAND, constant("FCALL"))
  .setHeader(RedisConstants.COMMAND, constant("my_func"))
  .process(exchange -> {
     Map<String, Object> keys = new HashMap<>();
     keys.put("key", "pair");

     exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelRedis.Values", keys);
  })
  .to(connection + "?redisTemplate=#redisTemplate")
  .log("Completed")
;
```

now when I do call the above, I do not get any error message saying "FCALL" is invalid and also do not see anything on Redis logs.

is there any way for me to see what is being sent? even putting in "HSET_FAKE" in the above router (.COMMAND()) does not generate any kind of error.